# How could I have handled this answer better?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

This answer was posted earlier: https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/32156/3169

I left a comment for the poster, a new user here on SE, letting them know about the back-up up policy.  I feel like this conversation could have gone more smoothly if I had approached my responses differently. Disengaging seems inadequate, because ideally this would be an educational experience for a new user (and valuable socialization into the community!).

How could I have handled this interaction differently to provide smoother feedback to the user?